# "Invisible" check-in during Team build

Tags: tfs

Our build process on Team Foundation Server 2010 does several check-ins. I don't want these check-ins to generate automatic e-mails et cetera.

I know there is a magical incantation to make this happen (if I recall correctly, a special naming convention for the check-in), but I cannot find it in the documentation to save my life.

So please, save my life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [*****NO_CI*****](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2007/07/27/tfs-2008-how-to-check-in-without-triggering-a-build-when-using-continuous-integration.aspx) as a checkin comment, that will prevent another build being triggered. Not sure if it does what you need though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, actually. Much appreciated.