# Jenkins & TFS: How to exclude commits done by the build itself from triggering another build

Tags: tfs, jenkins

In Jenkins, How can i exclude commits done by the build itself from triggering another build.?

I need this for TFS. It is possible with 'Subversion plugin' using "Excluded Users" option.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invisible" check-in during Team build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825986/invisible-check-in-during-team-build)

Comment: ***NO_CI*** might work if I use TFS as CI tool, but I need this for Jenkins.